# Base table or view not found (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Hola a todos necesito su ayuda ya que estoy intentando reiniciar contraseñas con laravel y necesito levantar la tabla `password_resets` pero el problema es que no puedo hacerlo, cuando intento hacer la migración me estos errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo malo es no me genera la tabla y no tengo ninguna tabla con ese nombre, al inicio pense que el problema era la conexión pero no puede ser porque el resto de consultas sql se generan correctamente a la tabla correspondiente, incluso no se si haga diferencia pero intente en lugar de `php artisan migrate` con `php artisan make:migration CreatePasswordResetsTable` y me dice que la tabla se creó correctamente pero cuando veo mi base de datos no esta creada la tabla, este es el codigo de error completo que se muestra en la página:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_master.password_resets' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` = example@example.com)
```

Desde ya gracias :).

### Edit 1

Después de comprobar que solo este una migración en la carpeta **database/migrations** intente hacer las migraciones y esta es la imagen de lo que me muestra la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aun así sigue sin crearme la tabla.

Comment: La tabla password_resets debe estar desde el inicio del proyecto, revisa que esté en las migraciones o intenta con `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Disculpa la pregunta pero ¿a qué te refieres con al inicio del proyecto?, por cierto ya intente con `composer dump-autoload` y tampoco funciono

Comment: laravel ya crea esa migración por defecto, por que tu la vuelves a crear? por eso debe ser el error ya que existen dos migraciones haciendo una creación de la misma tabla

Comment: @HeynerMartinez el problema es que no esta la tabla en la base de datos, solo están 4 que yo creé y la tabla **migrations** pero no la de `password_resets`

Comment: no esta en la base de datos, pero si en la carpeta migraciones del proyecto, revisa la carpeta Database/migrations

Comment: @HeynerMartinez si esta la migración ahí, que seguiría después de esto o que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: si tienes la migración ahí, elimina la que tu creaste (debería estar al final), por lo que debes de tener 2 migraciones con ese nombre, solo deja la que esta al principio y haces el php artisan migrate, puede que te de error, ya que si la tabla ya esta creada en la base de datos, la migración fallará

Comment: @HeynerMartinez ya hice lo que dijiste y si funciono, ya no me da error en la consola pero sigue sin crearme la tabla en la base de datos

Comment: en la consola te tiene que aparecer las migraciones que fueron creadas cuando le das php artisan migrate, agrega una captura para ver, también asegúrate que en el .env estas apuntando a la base de datos correcta

Comment: @HeynerMartinez ya actualice la pregunta con la imagen

Comment: @Davidflogar el error que te aparece es por que ya la tabla users existe, mira como funcionan las migraciones: cuando tu haces una migración por primera ves se crean las tablas que esten en la carpeta migraciones, ahora bien cuando tu vuelves a ejecutar el comando migrate, las migraciones intentan crear de nuevo las tablas en tu base de datos, como estas ya existen en tu base de datos, te dará error (que es lo que esta sucediendo ahorita)

Comment: @HeynerMartinez eso si lo entiendo, el problema es que como puedes ver ya no me da error, pero sigue sin crearme la table de `password_resets` :(

Comment: no te la crea porque encuentra un error y se detiene, las migraciones se ejecutan de manera secuencia, si te fijas todas empiezan con una fecha y hora de creación ese es el orden que se ejecutan, si una falla se interrumpen las demas, para poder ejecutarlas tendras que eliminar las tablas que se intentan crear en la migracion (OJO PERDERAS LOS DATOS, PORQUE SE ELIMINARÁN) te recomiendo que indagues primero en el tema de las migraciones para que veas como funcionan

Comment: @HeynerMartinez gracias, lo intente como dijiste y ya creó la tabla, y voy a hacer lo que dijiste e investigar mas de las migraciones